# Proof that: $\operatorname{ker} AB\subseteq \operatorname{ker} A+\operatorname{ker} B$

Tags: vector-spaces

$\newcommand{\ker}{\operatorname{ker}}$

Proof that: $\ker AB\subseteq\ker A+\ker B$

my solution:

$x\in \ker AB\to ABx=0\to \begin{cases} Ax=0\to x\in \ker A\\Bx=0\to x\in \ker B\end{cases}$

$\to x\in \ker A+\ker B\to \ker AB\subseteq \ker A+\ker B$

Question: Do it right? if false, the new right to do so?

Comment: The result you are trying to prove is false.

Comment: why is wrong?---

Comment: Take, $A=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{matrix}\right)$ and $B= \left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1\\
1 & 0
\end{matrix}\right)$

Comment: The result is just false : consider the case where $A,B$ are endomorpisms of $\Bbb R^2$, $A$ such that $\mathrm{Ker}(A)$ is the $x$-axis, and $B$ is the rotation of angle $\pi/2$. Then $\mathrm{Ker}(AB)$ is the $y$-axis, which is not included in $\mathrm{Ker}(A)+\mathrm{Ker}(B)=\mathrm{Ker}(A)=$ the $x$-axis.

Answer (score 3):

Note that we can have $x \in \ker(AB)$ with $x \not \in \ker(A)$ and $x \not \in \ker B$.  For example, take 
$$
A = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&0};\quad B=\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0}; \quad x=\pmatrix{1\\0}
$$
Note that $Ax \neq 0, Bx \neq 0,$ but $ABx=0$. Also, there are no vectors in the kernels of $A$ and $B$ whose sum is $x$.

I assume what you are trying to prove is that 
$$
\dim \ker AB \leq \dim \ker A + \dim \ker B
$$
However, you will have to try a different approach.

---

Assuming I have the correct definition, the fact that 
$$
\dim(\ker A + \ker B) \leq \dim \ker A + \dim \ker B
$$
follows directly from the fact that $\ker A, \ker B$ are subspaces of some vector space $V$.  So, we must prove that 
$$
\ker AB \leq \dim(\ker A + \ker B)
$$
My hint for this is that we may write
$$
\dim \ker(AB) = 
\dim(\ker(B) \cup (\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{Image}(B)))
= \dim\ker(B)+ \dim(\ker(A) \cap \operatorname{Image}(B))
$$
Why is this the case, and what does this statement allow you to conclude?

Comment: I want proof $\dim \ker AB \leq \dim(\ker A+\ker B)\leq \dim \ker A + \dim \ker B$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by $\ker A + \ker B$?  Do you mean $\{x+y: x \in \ker A \text{ and } y \in \ker B\}$?

Comment: $\dim(\ker A\cap \Image B)=??$

Comment: I forgot a $\leq$ up there but yes, $\ker A \cap \operatorname{Image}(B)$.  Think of it this way: if $x \in \ker(AB)$, then either $Bx = 0$, or $Bx \neq 0$ and $A(Bx) = 0$.

Comment: Ah, sorry, that should just be $(\ker(B))^c$.  My mistake.

Comment: Nope, had it right originally.

Comment: You are definitely right?

Comment: Yes, see my explanation.  Rather, I should ask: do you see the connection between my statement and the explanation I gave?

Answer (score 1):

$$
x\in \ker(AB) \iff ABx=0 \iff Bx\in \ker (A)\iff x \in B^{-1}(\ker(A)),
$$
i.e.
$$
\ker(AB)=B^{-1}(\ker(A)).
$$

Comment: No. $B$ (like $A$) might not be invertible.

Comment: This notation is probably not intended to imply $B$ is invertible -- it just refers to the inverse image under $B$

Comment: For a map $f: X \to Y$ and a subset $S$ of $Y$ the set $f^{-1}(S)$ is defined as $\{ x \in X: \ f(x)\in S\}$. $f$ need not be invertible.